# What are the weights of the San Fransisco font?

Tags: font, macos, font-book, beta-seed-program

What are the weights of the San Fransisco font?
More specifically: standard (not compact)

I'm pretty sure it's different for the two types (display and text).
I'd like to know both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I've got the solution:

In text:

- Light
- Regular
- Medium
- Semibold
- Bold
- Heavy

In display:

- Ultralight
- Thin
- Light
- Regular
- Medium
- Semibold
- Bold
- Heavy
- Black